# Solidity Value Assignment

Tags: solidity, ether, state-variable

Is there any way to assign a solidity variables value to current ether price and if it changes value will to?

Comment: You can use **Price Feeds** data to achieve that. You can read about [Chainlink Price Feeds](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds).

Comment: An alternative approach is to pull the price from DEX pairs, such as Uniswap's ETH-USDT.